# Use a .properties file keys in another .properties file

Tags: java, log4j

I have a `database.properties` file in my Java project that contains the hostname, username, password to my database. I use them in my code to connect to the database. The thing is, that I use log4j and inside the `log4j.properties` file I have to set the database hostname, username and password. These properties are needed so that log4j can log messages in the database.

In my project I have several modules that use log4j, so I'll have to set the database properties in multiple files.

Is there a way to use the keys from the `database.properties` file in the `log4j.properties` file?

Answer (score 0):

You may use a [PropertyConfigurator](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/PropertyConfigurator.html), load both properties files, and replace some properties of the `log4j.properties` file, with content from `database.properties` .

Then, pass it to the configurator.

```
    Properties dbProps = new Properties();
    FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream("database.properties");
    dbProps.load(in);
    in.close();

    Properties log4jProperties= new Properties();
    FileInputStream in2 = new FileInputStream("log4j.properties");
    log4jProperties.load(in2);
    in2.close();

    // replace things
    log4jProperties.setProperty("log4j.appender.DB.URL", dbProps.getProperty("db.url"));
    log4jProperties.setProperty("log4j.appender.DB.user", dbProps.getProperty("db.usr"));
    log4jProperties.setProperty("log4j.appender.DB.password", dbProps.getProperty("db.pwd"));

    // configure Log4j
    PropertyConfigurator.configure(log4jProperties);
```